# How to store array of string in Keychain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

i have followed "GenericKeychain" sample app from apple & already able to write a string into keychain & also able to read it from keychain.

But i am wondering how can i store an array of string inside keychain, Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: where is it ? @SAMIRRATHOD

Answer (score 6):

You can only store objects of type `CFDataRef` (which is toll-free bridged to `NSData`) in a keychain.

To store an array of strings you would typically use property list serialization:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"my", @"strings"];
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:myArray format: NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:NULL];
```

Now you can put `data` into the keychain.

Comment: Can we store model object array into the keychain ? If yes then how?